# FileCopy multiple files in multiple directories in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got a form with a command button to copy files from one directory to another based on some fields in a subform. When I click the button it only copies the file from the first record. How can I get it to copy the files from all the records?

`FileCopy "\\server\prod\processed\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.Source & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocType & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName, "C:\Users\temp\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName`

This is what I've tried now, but it still just gets the first record.

```
Dim rs As Recordset 
Set rs = Me.sfrmImages.Form.RecordsetClone

With rs
    .MoveFirst
Do While Not .EOF
    FileCopy "\\caddell.local\bin\cmic\cmicimaging\prod\processed\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.Source & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocType & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName, "C:\Users\brandonmorehouse\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName
.MoveNext

Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Open a recordset object (or just use the form RecordsetClone) and loop through records.

Comment: I tried doing this below, but it's saying that it can't find the recordset. I'm wanting to use the query I built as the recordset because there's 5 tables that make up that query.
```Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qryImages)
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True

        FileCopy "\\server\prod\processed\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.Source & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocType & "\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName, "C:\Users\brandonmorehouse\" & Me!sfrmImages.Form.DocName
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing```

Comment: Edit your question with attempted code, not drop into a comment. Why are you still referencing form controls instead of fields of recordset?

Comment: I tried the RecordsetClone, but it still only grabs the first record in the subform. Sorry, I'm a newbie when it comes to VBA and also using this site so I apologize.

Comment: You are still using the form in your code you need to use the recordset. ```![fieldname1]```, ```![fieldname2]``` instead of ```me.formcontrol```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference fields of recordset, not form fields/controls. Consider:

```
With Me.sfrmImages.Form.RecordsetClone
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        FileCopy "\\caddell.local\bin\cmic\cmicimaging\prod\processed\" & !Source & _
                "\" & !DocType & "\" & !DocName, "C:\Users\brandonmorehouse\" & !DocName
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed it to that and then I receive a run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection.

Comment: Make sure field names are correctly spelled. Edit question to show sample data as text table. Code referencing RecordsetClone fields works for me.

Comment: You rock! I ended up just naming the fields what the actual control source name is instead of a custom name and after doing that it worked. Thank you so much!!